# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.footballers index: data_1 dup key: { data: null }

Tags: express, mongoose

I have never had this issue before. I was creating instances easily all the time. But with this project it throwing me error about index or something. I don't even know what that is. Thank you in advance.

Here is my schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const footballersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('footballers', footballersSchema);
```

and is just simple controller which triggers creating a new instance

```
exports.checkUserForReg = async function(req, res, next){
            await footballersModel.create(req.body);
            res.(201).json({status: "Ok"})
}
```

but it gives me error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.footballers index: data_1 dup key: { data: null }`

Yes, every instance should have unique name field, but even when I try different it give me this error. I see error says `index: data_1 dup key: { data: null }`, but I don't have `index` key in my Schema at all! What is that ? Thank you!

Comment: Could you verify if the autogenerated index name isn't `data_1`?

Comment: I kind of figured. The thing is now I created collection myself, not through query express + mongoose. Now it works, but now if I need to create a collection I have to configure it.. Omgggg...